# Create a folder inside the component folder laravel

Tags: laravel, components

I have a project that will contain a lot of components, however I want to divide the folder of components into section as you can see:

[image: Screenshot folders]

However when I use the component inside the `test` folder I'm getting an error:

```
View [components.admin-panel-main-navbar] not found
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the . character to indicate if a component is nested deeper inside the components directory. For example, assuming the component is defined at resources/views/components/inputs/button.blade.php, you may render it like so:

```
<x-inputs.button/>
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#anonymous-components

So in your case

```
<x-test.admin-panel-main-navbar/>
```